# Convert array of strings to array of objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have this array containing strings with geographical data.
[image]

How can i turn it into an array of objects like this:

```
obj[0] = {lat:0, lng:0}
```

Comment: From where comes from this array? Cannot you change it server side?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try to use array.prototype.map to ease your work,

```
var newArray = arr.map(function(str){
 return JSON.parse("{" + str.substring(0,str.length - 1).replace(/lat/,'"lat"').replace(/lng/,'"lng"') + "}")
});
```

As well as, if you have the string in that array in a proper format, then some unnecessary `.replace()` can be removed which will results in performance boost.

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/yt46nynL/1/)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <script>
    var data = ["lat: 0, lng: 0;", "lat: 25.233, lng:22.455;"];
    var newData = new Array();
    for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
    {
        var temp = data[i].replace(/lat/g, "\"lat\"");
        temp = temp.replace(/lng/g, "\"lng\"");
        temp = temp.replace(/;/g, "");
        temp = "{" + temp + "}";
        newData.push(JSON.parse(temp));
    }
    console.log(newData);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```