# Make a JSON array of objects out of an array of strings

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array.

```
messages = ['hi', 'heelo', 'apple'];
```

Write a function to return:

```
[
    { msg: messages[0], type: 'A', label: 'msg' },
    { msg: messages[2], type: 'A', label: 'msg' },
    { msg: messages[2], type: 'A', label: 'msg' }
]
```

Comment: Let's see what you've tried, only then can we help you.

Comment: You should make an effort first.

Comment: `[0]` and then double `[2]`? Doesn't make any sense. And these hardcoded `type` and `label` keys...

Comment: @Kinduser Simple error on his side.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert array of strings to array of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31994643/convert-array-of-strings-to-array-of-objects)

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir It is better to await OP's response first, rather than throwing him into oblivion so soon.

Comment: @Taurus I just commeted so he can post his code. I neither downvoted the question nor any of the answers (I'm against that myself).

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir all great then :)

Answer (score -1):

You can use [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

> The map() method creates a new array with the results of calling a provided function on every element in the calling array.

```js
var messages = ['hi', 'heelo', 'apple'];

var messages_1 = JSON.stringify(messages.map(function(el) {
  return {
    msg: el,
    type: "A",
    label: "msg"
  };
}));

console.log(messages_1);
```